# Addition of independent discrete random variables. Where are the n values coming from and how do I find the pmf?

Tags: probability, independence

Consider that $X$ and $Y$ are independent integer-valued random variables with mass functions $p_X$ and $p_Y$. Prove that the random variable $Z := X + Y$ has the mass function $$p_Z(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} p_X(n)p_Y(x-n)$$

How I tried to solve the problem: since $X$ and $Y$ are independent $P_{X,Y}(x,y) = P_X(x) \cdot P_Y(y)$

$$P_Z(x) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\sum P_{X,Y}(x,y) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}P_X(x)\left(\sum_{y=1}^{z-x}P_Y(y)\right) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} P_X(x)\cdot(P_Y(z-x)) = \sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} {{P_X(x)} \cdot {P_y(z-x)}}$$

Also how do I find the bounds for the summations?

Comment: Please don't link to unsearchable images.  Use *MathJax*.

Comment: Sorry new to this, I will fix it

Comment: As written, the first equiality makes little sense